# What is the difference between `opencv.android.JavaCameraView` and `opencv.android.NativeCameraView`

Tags: java, android, opencv, camera

Exacly as stated in the subject: What is the difference between `opencv.android.JavaCameraView` and `opencv.android.NativeCameraView`. What are advantages one over the other, the main ones, which gives more options?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

From the [OpenCV documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/android_binary_package/dev_with_OCV_on_Android.html?highlight=nativecameraview):

The `org.opencv.android.JavaCameraView` class is implemented inside OpenCV library. It is inherited from `CameraBridgeViewBase`, that extends `SurfaceView` and uses standard Android camera API. Alternatively you can use `org.opencv.android.NativeCameraView` class, that implements the same interface, but uses `VideoCapture` class as camera access back-end. `opencv:show_fps="true"` and `opencv:camera_id="any"` options enable FPS message and allow to use any camera on device. Application tries to use back camera first.

Implementation of `CvCameraViewListener` interface allows you to add processing steps after frame grabbing from camera and before its rendering on screen. The most important function is `onCameraFrame`. It is callback function and it is called on retrieving frame from camera. The callback input is object of `CvCameraViewFrame` class that represents frame from camera.

Comment: It is still unclear which one is better for the image processing like human detection.. gettin array of pixels etc.

Comment: Can someone expand on the difference between the Android Camera API and the OpenCV VideoCapture class from a usage point of view? Performance, Features, Stability, Is the VideoCapture class only accessible from c/c++?

Comment: As this is an old post, I'll post only a comment.  It's recommended to use Java implementation whenever it's possible. All the JNI calls cost a lot in terms of performance, the same goes for mmaped memory usage. This applies not only to the camera usage.

Answer (score 12):

I just took this answer from [here](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/android-opencv/G7bwR5nkVfc/alK3FeDrJsIJ) (Which is a bit old answer) and added what I experienced:

native camera:

- (+1) higher framerate
- (+1) capture RGBA, no need to convert from android yuv format.
- "compiled only for armv7 architecture" not true anymore.
- **(-1) not work on all devices -> I confirm !! This is why I don't use it !!** see [bug 2359](http://code.opencv.org/issues/2359).
- (-1) not support autofocus, setting gain.. (answered in 2012)

I hope this can be helpful !