# Difference between NativeCameraView and JavaCameraView in OpenCV

Tags: java, android, opencv, computer-vision, native

As in the topic, could someone please explain to me what is the difference using NativeCameraView and JavaCameraView in OpenCV?

Currently I am using JavaCameraView to detect fingertips and it is extremely slow. I am wondering if using NativeCameraView would make a change?

Answer (score 2):

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/android-opencv/G7bwR5nkVfc/alK3FeDrJsIJ

[What is the difference between `opencv.android.JavaCameraView` and `opencv.android.NativeCameraView`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16626343/what-is-the-difference-between-opencv-android-javacameraview-and-opencv-andro)

can help you a bit.