# OpenCV for Android - does NativeCameraView still exist?

Tags: java, android, opencv, image-processing

I'm an experienced OpenCV user attempting to get up to speed with OpenCV for Android.  I've found multiple references to a class "NativeCameraView", for example:

[Difference between NativeCameraView and JavaCameraView in OpenCV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17938265/difference-between-nativecameraview-and-javacameraview-in-opencv)

[What is the difference between `opencv.android.JavaCameraView` and `opencv.android.NativeCameraView`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16626343/what-is-the-difference-between-opencv-android-javacameraview-and-opencv-andro)

http://docs.opencv.org/java/2.4.8/org/opencv/android/NativeCameraView.html

https://github.com/Tinker-S/OpenCVSamples/blob/master/OpenCV%20Library%20-%202.4.3/src/org/opencv/android/NativeCameraView.java

But these are all from at least a few years ago.  When I go to:

https://github.com/opencv/opencv

and put "NativeCameraView" in the "This Repository", "Search" box at the top I get no results.  If I search for "JavaCameraView" I get 11 results.

Also, if I go to

http://docs.opencv.org/java/3.1.0/

JavaCameraView is listed but NativeCameraView is not.

Was NativeCameraView removed as of OpenCV 3 ??  Is there a change log or similar somewhere that covers the current state of JavaCameraView vs NativeCameraView ??  Please advise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NativeCameraView was dropped in OpenCV 3, according to the [ChangeLog](http://code.opencv.org/projects/opencv/wiki/ChangeLog#30):

> The other, a bit sad but inevitable news - we had to drop support for nativecamera on Android. It used some undocumented API and never worked stable.