# It seems that your device does not support camera(or it is locked)

Tags: java, android, opencv, android-camera

`Android opencv` samples and tutorials were running fine and suddenly one day I get this for all of those:
`"It seems that your device does not support camera (or it is locked). The application will be closed"`
Please help, how to I can fix it?

I have reinstalled opencv and imported again and made new emulators but the problem still persists.

Comment: turn off the device and re-boot. Try reinstalling opencv again.

Comment: take a look at this: http://answers.opencv.org/question/1574/camera-not-working

Comment: I had meet same issue, and it solved with the following way.
See http://stackoverflow.com/a/42661642/5850039

Answer (score 37):

Go to your device settings -> apps -> YOUR APP -> Permissions -> turn on camera permission..

Worked for me..

Comment: This is what I had to do. Not sure why the permission wasn't granted.

Comment: @AutonomousApps, Because you are using an API/Build Tools > 23

Comment: Worked for me, but requesting the permissions from the user as in Geraldo's answer should be better.

Comment: To solve it on runtime, not manually, check my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44087946/4398784.

Answer (score 19):

Check the camera permission in AndroidManifest.xml.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>

    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera"/>
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus"/>
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.front"/>
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.front.autofocus"/>
```

Its working for me..

Answer (score 11):

From the [Android Docs](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html):

> Beginning in Android 6.0 (API level 23), users grant permissions to
>   apps while the app is running, not when they install the app.

It means that on Android 23 or above, besides the manifest, you need to request permission on runtime as well. In this case, camera access.

To do this, you can use the code below:

```
// First check android version 
if (MyVersion > Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP_MR1) {
//Check if permission is already granted
//thisActivity is your activity. (e.g.: MainActivity.this)
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(thisActivity,
                    Manifest.permission.CAMERA)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        // Give first an explanation, if needed.
        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(thisActivity,
                Manifest.permission.CAMERA)) {

            // Show an explanation to the user *asynchronously* -- don't block
            // this thread waiting for the user's response! After the user
            // sees the explanation, try again to request the permission.

        } else {

            // No explanation needed, we can request the permission.

            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(thisActivity,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA},
                    1);
        }
    }
}
```

You can also handle the request response, as described on the [docs](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html).

*Hope it helps!*

Comment: Where do I add this code? This doesnt seem to be jhava code at all, getting many errors when I try to paste it somewhere in MainActivity, please clarify where to add

Comment: Hi, Mich! It is Java. I suggest you to read the docs linked on the answer so that you get more detailed and updated information.

Answer (score 2):

Just had this problem and I solved it by killing any other apps that were using the camera. I had some previous tutorials still running in the background.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, the issue was
My application use `Android Camera` in *another activity*
And *another activity* **was not release the `Camera` after use it on Destroyed (lock it)**
And after I release the `Camera` on the another activity, this dialog will not showed again.

So generally to fix this issue

1. Check CAMERA permissions
2. Check CAMERA not locked (by releasing it after usage in any other activities)

Comment: related question about release 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11495842/how-surfaceholder-callbacks-are-related-to-activity-lifecycle

Answer (score 0):

The samples should work because they are using the JavaCamera. I get this problem when I tried to use the Native one. It seems to be that the native one doesn't work for ervery phone. see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28130605/3014036).

I have to add that **in some devices the openCV native camera doesn't work at all** , [bug 2359](http://code.opencv.org/issues/2359).

Comment: I faced a similar issue when running on emulator, and the solution was: Go emulator, `Setting->Apps->my_app->Permissions` and then enable "Camera".
I found it being requested but not enabled.