# Open CV giving error, "It seems that you device does not support camera (or it is locked) despite providing camera permission in Android manifest file

Tags: android, c++, opencv, camera

Open CV giving error, "It seems that you device does not support camera (or it is locked). Application will be closed." despite  providing camera permission in Android manifest file.

Open CV version - 2.4.11
Can someone please help on this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20666366/it-seems-that-your-device-does-not-support-cameraor-it-is-locked Can you check this answer?

Comment: I tried all the options mentioned in above link but no luck