# Opencv with native android

Tags: android, eclipse, opencv, android-ndk, eclipse-cdt

Can we use opencv in android use `ndk` i am trying it from last 15/20 days , it give me running program sometime and sometime show me error's , as i think i configured it right as well , my previous question regarding it is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22962206/errors-while-running-program-in-eclipse) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22929038/native-android-tutorial-is-giving-error) , i am using `android 2.4.8` with `ndk-8` on `64bit windows` , i also tried `opencv 2.4.4` but there is no sample for native is given there

Answer (score 0):

You could try using [SWIG](http://www.swig.org/) to generate the bindings.

It's not straight forward to make it work, but it saves you a lot of work.