# How to get rid of the padding above and below this JavaCameraView?

Tags: android-layout, opencv, surfaceview, android

In my OpenCV app, in the following layout, the root ViewGroup is a `FrameLayout` with `android:layout_width="match_parent"` and `android:layout_height="match_parent"`, and has *no* `android:padding`.

This FrameLayout contains a `JavaCameraView` which also has `android:layout_width="match_parent"` as well as `android:layout_height="match_parent"`, and has *no* `android:layout_margin`.

So the `JavaCameraView` should span the entire screen. But instead, it has a black padding above and below it. **How can I get rid of this padding above and below `JavaCameraView`?**

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16626343/what-is-the-difference-between-opencv-android-javacameraview-and-opencv-andro#answer-16626399), `JavaCameraView` inherits from `SurfaceView`. So it should respect the layout_width and layout_height properties of itself and its parent in the view hierarchy right?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <org.opencv.android.JavaCameraView 
        android:id="@+id/mainActivity_javaCameraView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</FrameLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: The surface view fills its parent. This is the camera picture not being rotated, cut off, or scaled to fit the surface view

Comment: @DavidMedenjak You are right. I just tested that by giving the JavaCameraView a `android:background` color. It seems to fill the parent. But then I need the camera frame to fill the parent as well. Do you know how to force that camera frame to fill the parent?

Comment: I haven't done much with this myself, I just wanted to clear this misconception about padding

Comment: @DavidMedenjak OK. Thank you for clarifying that =)

Answer (score 0):

I am 4 years late but hopefully this will help someone. I found a solution here: [OpenCV Android Camera Not Fullscreen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38835077/opencv-android-camera-not-fullscreen)

I just followed the steps provided by Md Juyel Rana and it worked like a charm. Hopefully this will help someone.